# Reinitialize all array elements to zero java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I have a 2-D array which needs to be reinitialized to 0 after every iteration
what is the best (fastest) method to do so.

- Using a for loop doing it in a tradition way
- Or assign memory to it again by doing `myarray=new long[size][size];`

  ```
  long myarray[][]=new long[size][size]
  for(.....)
  {
       //..do something with myarray
       //..set all elements of myarray to 0 for next iteration
  }
  ```

PS- I need it for optimization in Coding Competitions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-long:A-long-) function:

```
for (long[] subarray : myarray) {
  Arrays.fill(subarray, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This "answer" does not actually answer the question (i.e., what's the fastest way), but it _does_ point out that there is a third condender for fastest method that the OP didn't think of.

Comment: Since Arrays.fill() method's time complexity is O(N), total complexity of your code is O(N^2). Even though array initialization costs O(N), it is much faster in practice.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you don't need to explicity set all elements to zero. `myarray=new long[size][size]` will fill default values of zero in the elements. See  [Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or **array component is initialized with a *default value* when it is created** (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> - For type `byte`, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (byte)0.
> - For type `short`, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (short)0.
> - For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
> - **For type `long`, the default value is zero, that is, 0L**.

If the size is big though, it's more efficient to set the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myarray[i].length; j++) {
        myarray[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your statement:
" _You don't need to explicity set all elements to zero. myarray=new long[size][size] will fill default values of zero in the elements_ " ...Is valid when CREATING the array for the first time.What i want is after that.Please read the question carefully.Please. OR do i consider the last part of your answer as the real answer

Comment: @Vulcan I already read the question carefully :). I just wanted to point that the one line statement already does this. But if memory is important use the last part.

Comment: To also note that in the first part, the previously used memory would be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Comment: So doesnt that implicitly mean that last part would be faster? As in the first part gc kicks in.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes it would faster. But it really depends on the memory and how often the GC runs.